# Using IReadOnlyList with Unity for Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to use something like this for my Hololens project

```
public struct FD
{
    public FD(string name, IEnumerable<double> ce)
    {
        Name = name;
        CE = new ReadOnlyCollection<double>(new List<double>(ce));
    }
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly IReadOnlyList<double> CE;       
}
```

However Unity does not seem to use .NET 4.5 and therfore there is no `IReadOnlyList`.

Something similar happened to me in the past with Unity not supporting some features I wanted. However once they pass out of the Unity Editor they can be compiled -or so I remember

So how about this?

```
public struct FD
{
    public FD(string name, IEnumerable<double> ce)
    {
        Name = name;
        CE = new ReadOnlyCollection<double>(new List<double>(ce));
    }
    public readonly string Name;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public readonly IList<double> CE;
#else
    public readonly IReadOnlyList<double> CE;
#endif   
}
```

In this case when using the unity editor only a `IList` is consider but once after that the `IReadOnlyList` is used. What do you think about this? Or what is your approach to use `IReadOnlyList` with a Hololens project?

Comment: Too bad it's not supported but maybe just store the list as an enumerabe?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an up-to-date version of Unity you can [configure](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRuntimeUpgrade.html) your project to use .NET 4.5+ features.

1. Go to 'Edit' -> 'Project settings' -> 'Player'.
2. In the settings tab look for 'Other Settings' -> 'Configuration' -> 'Scripting Runtime Version'. Set this to '.NET 4.x Equivalent.'

As of Unity 2018.1 this mode [is considered](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/28/updated-scripting-runtime-in-unity-2018-1-what-does-the-future-hold/) stable and 'ready for widespread use.' As well as `IReadOnlyList` you can use good stuff like async/await and other modern features.

Comment: That is great news. I knew about the settings but didn't know it was stable.